# Software Manager error, cannot update repo 'nux-desktop'

Tags: centos, software-updates

This is the error that I encounter in my Software Manager (linebreaks added for readability):

```
failed to refresh cache: cannot update repo 'nux-dextop': 
  cannot download repomd.xml: 
    cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: 
      all mirrors were tried; Last error:
        status code: 400 for http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/http://mirror.li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

Comment: With a small repo like nux, it's always possible that "all" (i.e. the) available repo server is currently down for updates or whatever. I wouldn't be overly worried unless the problem persists for a day or two. FWIW, li.nux.ro seemed to work for me, mirror.li.nux.ro does not seem to mirror nux anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the

> nux-dextop.repo

file in /etc/yum.repos.d folder.

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nux-dextop.repo
```

It should work now